# float right vertically align

Tags: html, css

How can I align these two icons with a `float: right`?

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/vz1OAHM2rn6zoRHBYaTU?p=preview)

HTML

```
<li>
  <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/102031900129645/picture?type=square" />
  <a href=""> Johnny Smith </a>
  <span class="">
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
  </span>
</li>
```

CSS

```
li {
  width: 200px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

span {
  float: right;
  vertical-align: middle; // not working
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to align the icons with the text, for span

```
.span {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

Simple that way.

Answer (score 0):

Floated elements don't obey `vertical-align`. You need `display: inline-block;` instead: http://plnkr.co/edit/zTdoW4TBUbREzI4ADTQO?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `line-height`:

```
span {
  float: right;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/bE1dEvtEp60SpiobfUje?p=preview